# Testing react component state onChange

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test this component

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/no-onchange */
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { } from 'prop-types'
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

export class RangeFilter extends Component {
  static propTypes = {}
  static defaultProps = {}

  state = {
    id: this.props.id,
    value: null,
    option: '',
    valid: true,
  }

  onSelectChange = (event) => {
    const selectValue = event.target.value
    this.setState({ option: selectValue }, () => this.props.rangeFilter({
      id: this.props.id,
      value: this.state.value,
      option: this.state.option,
    }))
  }

  onFilterChange = (event) => {
    const filterValue = event.target.value
    if (filterValue < 0) {
      this.setState({ valid: false, value: filterValue })
    } else {
      this.setState({ valid: true, value: filterValue },
        () => this.props.rangeFilter({
          id: this.props.id,
          value: this.state.value,
          option: this.state.option,
        }))
    }
  }

  setStyle = () => {
    if (this.state.valid) {
      return {
        width: '70%',
      }
    } else {
      return {
        width: '70%',
        border: '2px solid #e89b9b',
      }
    }
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props
    return (
      <div className={classes.filter}>
        <input
          style={this.setStyle()}
          type="number"
          min="0"
          onChange={this.onFilterChange}
        />

        <select
          onChange={this.onSelectChange}
          value={this.state.option}
          className={classes.select}
          disabled={!this.state.value}
        >
          <option value="">=</option>
          <option value="<">&lt;</option>
          <option value=">">&gt;</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const styles = {
  select: {
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  filter: {
    width: '100%',
  },
}

export default withStyles(styles)(RangeFilter)
```

with this test

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'

import RangeFilter from '../RangeFilter'

describe('<RangeFilter /> component', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    const rangeFilter = shallow(
      <RangeFilter />
    )
    expect(rangeFilter).toHaveLength(1)
  })

  it('should set option to <', () => {
    const rangeFilter = mount(<RangeFilter rangeFilter={() => {}} />)
    rangeFilter.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: '<' } })
    expect(rangeFilter.state.option).toBe('<')
  })
})
```

but I can't get it to work. I'm new to react testing and I can't find any clear documentation or tutorials on how to test anything more complex than clicking a button. All I really want to test is the onSelectChange method but I guess you have to simulate the on change event. I tried to use the shallow rendering but couldn't get that to work. When using mount I can get the method to execute but state is just an empty object so there's nothing to update or make any expectations about. This is the output of the test.

```
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected value to be:
      "<"
    Received:
      undefined

    Difference:

      Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.

      15 |     const rangeFilter = mount(<RangeFilter rangeFilter={() => {}} />)
      16 |     rangeFilter.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: '<' } })
    > 17 |     expect(rangeFilter.state.option).toBe('<')
      18 |   })
      19 | })
      20 |
```

If I use shallow instead of mount:

```
Method “simulate” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

      20 |   it('should set option to <', () => {
      21 |     const rangeFilter = shallow(<RangeFilter rangeFilter={() => {}} />)
    > 22 |     rangeFilter.find('select').simulate('change', { target: { value: '<' } })
      23 |     expect(rangeFilter.state.option).toBe('<')
      24 |   })
      25 | })
```

Basically, I want to know how to test a method in a react component.

Comment: is your component working fine?

Comment: try using shallow instead of mount

Comment: The component works exactly as expected. I just want to write some tests for it. Ideally I would like to call the components methods with different inputs and confirm that state has been updated with the correct values. I don't know how to do this with react components.

Comment: If I use shallow I can't use .find('select') to find the select element and simulate the change event

Comment: you can use find in shallow

Comment: I can use it but it just throws an error. See updated question

Comment: try passing all the props your component want. Coz when I used it, it was doing its job

Comment: for the mount case use rangeFilter.state('option') this will do your work

Comment: What does that mean? Use it how? Like this, expect(rangeFilter.state('option')).toBe('<'). That gives me the same error